# How many clock cycles for variable assignment in C?

Tags: java, c, performance

Does anyone know how many clock cycles it takes for a variable assignment in C language on a x86 platform? It is generally  considered to take less when compared to java, what is the reason behind it?

Comment: How will an answer help you?

Comment: It depends the type of assignement i=1; different than i=j;

Comment: Just to get an idea of the overhead involved in java. eg : i=j;

Comment: It depends on a load of stuff.  It can take from no cycles (like maybe the varible gets optimised out completely) to lots (like it ends up being swapped to a hard drive).  Everyone knows C is quicker than java, people don't use java to try to go really fast

Comment: My (imaginary) computer does it in approximately 1/16 clock cycle: I mean, it can do 16 variable assignments in parallel and each one takes 1 clock cycle ... so 1/16 clock cycle :)

Comment: C isn't quick in all cases, Many people would be surprised to know memory allocation is faster in java where it is just bump the pointer on a heap. I would be interested to know more about the number of instructions that gets generated by the jvm in case of a simple variable assignment.

Comment: Measure it and you'll know the answer.

Answer (score 5):

The difference between C and Java is not depending on the difference between the languages themselves, but rather on the difference of technology behind those two languages:

C is compiled in binary, which is the code that gets directly executed by the processor. By opposition, Java is (most generally) never compiled totally, it is instead pseudo-compiled into [bytecode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_bytecode).

This bytecode is designed to be interpreted by a virtual machine (the JVM in the case of Java), allowing for a much easier portability: while you need to adapt your C code to make it portable (see NetBSD for an example), or make different versions of it for each target; you just need a different JVM to run the same java bytecode on a different target.

It is worth noting that Java follows the [JIT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Just-in-time_compilation) model, allowing for optimizations that are normally impossible, since they rely on conditions only known at run-time.

Now, in the case of your question, the real things to compare are: for a given machine, how much cycles does it take for a value to get copied in memory (RAM, even though that some C compilers can use CPU registers to store variables used a lot in a short time-span, like loop counters for example) with the assembly instruction versus how much cycles does the JVM take to do the same task upon reading the Java bytecode instruction to do so.

And I would say that with a good JVM implementation, there would be no difference for the allocation itself, as far as I understand. Now, there are other criteria to consider: Java usually makes heavy usage of objects, that take a lot of place in RAM, due to their complex nature, and therefore, take also more time to allocate. Also, I believe that Java makes more checks to avoid common mistakes, such as accessing a non-initialized variable, and those cost time too.

But keep in mind that a badly coded C program can take much more time to execute than a very well coded Java program.

Answer (score 3):

Only after you understand this statement:
"Exactly zero lines of C code have ever been executed by a computer.  Also, exactly zero lines of Java code have ever been executed by a computer."

You will never understand any answer to your question.

There answer to your question is:
"An assignment, written in C, takes an unknown number of clock cycles to complete."